# Is there any way to write the value of a register directly to a file?

Tags: c++, assembly, file-io, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I'm trying to make something that prints remainder divided by denominator as a fraction in base ten.

Because I <strike>fear</strike> don't like unaligned memory access, I use a register to buffer the last eight computed digits.

However, I could not find any way to write the buffer directly to the output.

I know I can move the buffer into memory and write that, but I prefer not to do that.

Is there any way to write the value of a register directly to a file?

I'm using inline assembly in C++ with gcc-4.7 on 64-bit Ubuntu.

**Edit:**

I am very sorry for asking such an incredibly stupid question.

I was playing around with inline assembly and tried to efficiently write the output I generated byte-by-byte to the output. I attempted this by shifting the bytes that were generated into a single register, storing that register in memory and writing the 8 bytes at that memory address to the output (although I'm not sure if this would be endian-compatible).

What I had in mind when asking this question was somehow omitting "storing that register in memory." In the end I just stored the register to a buffer each time it contained 8 bytes, and when the buffer was filled I printed the entire buffer instead of 8 bytes at a time.

I hope this clarifies the reasoning behind my seemingly strange question.

Comment: What operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: @RPFeltz, I think you may want to investigate using a debugger like GDB. XEmacs has a graphical UI for GDB which will probably be easier for a new user. Alternatively maybe someone else can recommend one (I am not familiar with recent Linux debugging tools - the last time I used a debugger on an *n*x platform was over 10 years ago - probably there are better ones).

Comment: @Ben I use Eclipse CDT with GDB. What exactly do you mean by investigating?

Comment: You seem to be asking how to find the contents of a register reliably. The answer is "use a debugger".

Comment: With your edits, why don't you just have a buffer 8 bytes long?

Comment: Because this way I use less system calls. I'm not sure if that is a good thing, but I thought it was.

Answer (score 2):

"Is there any way to write the value of a register directly to a file?"

No.

"Because I fear unaligned memory access, I use a register to buffer the last eight computed digits."

**You cannot write computer programs on the assumption that the computer is hostile.** In order to write a program you must assume the computer behaves in a regular and predictable way.

In your case, you must write the program in such a way that unaligned access is not possible. Since you are writing in assembler, this is your responsibility, not the compiler's.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how you think file IO works, that such a thing could be desirable. The idea of writing a register to persistent storage surely went out with Drum Memory computers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_memory. In reality, IO in standard architectures works at the lowest level by writing the data to a shared memory block then instructing the hardware device to read that memory and write it to the destination.